# how to use the codes of a css document inline in html document

Tags: html, css, inline

I wanted to create a contact-us page with HTML(no CSS document is allowed to use), then I found what I wanted but the code is written in 2 documents, HTML code is written in HTML document and the styles are in the CSS document. I'm looking for a way to use the CSS codes inline in the HTML document. Could you help me, please?

Comment: I've already found a way to do this, simply copy the CSS code and paste it into the <style> tag in the <body> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p {
      color: green
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>All your custom CSS can go in the head section of the HTML</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a style tag like this: `<style> </style>` and inside will go the CSS.

It's good practice to keep your CSS in a seperate file to make the code look cleaner